# ValidateRequest in MVC not truly aborting the request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, xss

I'm testing my MVC3 web app for XSS attacks and I'm noticing a weird behavior with the default `ValidateRequest` in .Net

I have a form with a few text fields and when I enter a 'dangerous' string such as:

```
<img src=x onerror=alert(/XSS/.source)>
```

I see the "A potentially dangerous Request.Form was detected..." message pop up as expected.

My understanding is that this validation will automatically cancel the request and no changes will take place. However, when I refresh the page, I'm seeing that the text field in question now displays a value of 'ED7F9'

Something similar occurs if I try to save a value of `<script>alert("hi")</script>`. In this case, after the validation message, the remaining text in the field is: "alert("

Has anyone seen this before of have any clues as to why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure your're using the updated final version of AntiXSS and ASP.NET MVC. No beta please!

Comment: I'm not using the AntiXSS library. This is using the default MVC3 Razor encoding.